# ${surefire.forkNumber} always resolving as null

Tags: maven

I am using ${surefire.forkNumber} in system property in my pom. According to maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html), it should be resolved to the number of fork that is currently running. But it is resolving as null.
Below is snippet of my pom file:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                         <database.name>My_Test_Schema_${surefire.forkNumber}</database.name>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Am I missing anything?

Please, anybody throw some light...

Comment: Post your complete pom (or at least plugin definition), please.

Answer (score 6):

It might be that `${surefire.forkNumber}` is substituted *twice*: first by maven-core, and then by surefire. Since maven-core doesn't know about this property, it substitutes `null` there.

Solution: protect from first substitution by quoting `$`:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <database.name>My_Test_Schema_$${surefire.forkNumber}</database.name>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Source: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/SureFire-2-16-doesn-t-respect-forkCount-td5771850.html#a5771855

This one worked for me --- I had the same problem. It's a pity this isn't documented.

Answer (score 2):

Pass setting via VM -D within argLine:

```
<argLine>-Ddatabase.name=My_Test_Schema_${surefire.forkNumber}</argLine>
```

I found systemPropertyVariables to be quite fragile. See [SureFire 2.16 doesn't respect forkCount](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/SureFire-2-16-doesn-t-respect-forkCount-td5771850.html#a5771855) (which didn't work for me one way or the other using surefire 2.17).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the place holder ${surefire.forkNumber} within argLine, or within the system properties

```
You should pass the value to  place holder either these three ways..

 1. command line argument  like mvn test -Dsurefire.forkNumber=8

 2.  set by  systemPropertyVariables System.setProperty("surefire.forkNumber",8);

 3. set by pom properties tag like

 <properties>
        <surefire.forkNumber>8</surefire.forkNumber>
    </properties>
```

Comment: The first option will just be resolved as a string, i.e, wherever this property is used, it will be replaced by 8. surefire.forkNumber is a maven built in property. Its actual feature is to substitute 1 to n number of the string with which it is used, where n is the forkcount metioned in the plugin config. For better understanding, you may read it [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/SureFire-2-16-doesn-t-respect-forkCount-td5771850.html). guess the other two options also ends up likewise.